# AcquireTokenSilient of MSAL is not working for Azure AD users

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

Our organization has a on Azure Active directory, we wanted our application to be exposed to internal users (Azure AD users) and also to the external users who are not part of AD

We implemented this through Azure B2C Custom policies and were able to integrate our custom applications using MSAL library.

We have set the token expiry as 15 minutes and after 15 minutes we are trying to get the `accessToken` to access the backend APIs. We are successfully able to get the `accessToken` for B2C users however for AD users MSAL library is throwing error `Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'`.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with MSAL 1.x library as refresh token happens in hidden iframe in MSAL 1.x library.

Recommendation is to use MSAL 2.x library which doesn't uses iframe for token fresh and doesn't result in this error.